# How to make test payments on Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I need to work on an existing `OpenCart` application which I cloned and set up locally. I need to make test purchases but I'm afraid it'll actually charge my card. How can I make it so that payments don't actually go through?

Comment: How can I do the 'boogie' and make sure nobody else looks? Kinda like the same question, [no effort and research whatsoever](https://www.google.nl/search?q=OpenCart+test+payment).

Comment: Those all have to do with Paypal, I'm asking about card purchases.

Comment: It shows more then 1 result....

Comment: I said they ALL have to do with Paypal. I didn't have a Paypal account and I didn't want to create one. It looks like I'll have to make one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest to you: [paypal_sandbox.pdf](http://oc15131.demo.goleo.vn/index.php?route=information/resourcedetail/download&resource_id=1) (found it [here](http://oc15131.demo.goleo.vn/index.php?route=information/resourcedetail&resource_id=1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may follow below steps to test product buy process

1. set payment option at admin panel - set it to cash on delivery
2. open opencart front site and put items in cart
3. go to check out page and choose cash on delivery option.

one other option is to test it against the paypal sandbox.